# How can I use JSON image file object on ejs

Tags: node.js, json, ejs

I want to use an image on my ejs code, but I use loop with JSON array, so I want to make image url to object of JSON.

I put the JSON object way on the source code.

```
{
  "champion" : 
  [
  {
    "id": "266",
    "key": "Aatrox",
    "name": "Aatrox",
    "origin": ["Demon"],
    "class": ["Blademaster"],
    "cost": 3,
    "img" : "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.17.1/img/champion/Aatrox.png",
```

This json file's local data name is "cdata".

```
<!-- Champion Data -->
<% for(var i=0; i<cdata.champion.length; i++){ %>
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 mb-12">
        <div class="card border-left-primary shadow h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                    <div class="col mr-2">
                        <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-3"><h3><%= cdata.champion[i].name %></h3></div>
                        <img src= <%= "cdata.champion[0].img" %> class="ChampionImage__ChampImage-xj39xo-2 fhAQxz">
                        <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800"><%= cdata.champion[i].key %></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

My website shows broken image https://ykyuen.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/svg-image-broken.png

after that, I changed the code to

```
<img src= "<%= cdata.champion[0].img %>" class="ChampionImage__ChampImage-xj39xo-2 fhAQxz">
```

and

```
<img src= <%= cdata.champion[0].img %> class="ChampionImage__ChampImage-xj39xo-2 fhAQxz">
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: did you check the url getting rendered in the html, using inspect?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code from using `for` loop to use `.forEach` Here is [docs](https://ejs.co/#docs)

```
<% cdata.champion.forEach(function(champion){ %>
  <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 mb-12">
    <div class="card border-left-primary shadow h-100 py-2">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col mr-2">
                    <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-3"><h3><%= champion.name %></h3></div>
                    <img src="<%= champion.img %>" class="ChampionImage__ChampImage-xj39xo-2 fhAQxz">
                    <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800"><%= champion.key %></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <i class="fas fa-calendar fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
<% }) %>
```

In my case, I've used `<img src="<%= image %>"` and it worked.
Of course, the code should work only in case of correctly parsed JSON.